# Concatenating multiple fields in Model to display in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to concatenate three fields to display in a ListBox.  I have tried both in the Model and in the code behind the Windows Form.  Seems like, I can pull one field and it works.  But as soon as I try to concatenate fields, it fails.

I have googled and tried concatenating the fields in the model, several different ways. No success.

Here is my Model (the part that is relevant)

```
[Key]
public int transaction_id { get; set; }

[StringLength(1)]
public string v_noaccess_flag { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
public string v_lastname { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(25)]
public string v_firstname { get; set; }

[StringLength(12)]
public string h_phone { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string fullname
{
    get { return h_lastname + ", " + h_firstname + ", " + h_phone; }
}

public int ID { set { transaction_id = value; } }
```

And Here is the code that I use to populate the ListBox

```
try
{
    // Find results that match the last name field, entered in Textbox1 by user
    var lstNames = oBadger_Host.EntityList.Where(a => a.h_lastname == textBox1.Text.Trim()).ToList();

    listBox1.DisplayMember = "fullname";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
    listBox1.DataSource = lstNames;
    listBox1.Refresh();
    listBox1.Update();              

}
```

When I run it as is above, My ListBox is populated with the following (for each time there is a record associated to the last name)

Badger.Business.Badger_Host

Badger.Business is namespace.  Badger_Host is model

I can confirm the ID is working in the NotMapped fields.  Because, if I set the DisplayMember = "ID" I get the correct ID's for each record to display.

I can't figure out what's wrong with my concatenation. What am I doing wrong here?  I have been working on this for almost two days now and, my lack of experience in C# and being 12 years since I worked with Windows Forms has me at a brick wall

Comment: shouldn't it be v_firstname and v_lastname

Comment: @Clint - Ha!  What an idiot, I feel like!!  All this time, I have been working from the wrong Model!  I was calling host names from visitor model (thus the v_).  I need new glasses for sure.  Thank you for being a second pair of eyes.  That has resolved my issue.  Tonight, I will down a few shots in your honor!!!  Thank you!!

Comment: We all do it, an extra pair of eyes can do wonders :D

Comment: Hi @ExecChef, would you be able to mark the answer has resolved, when you have time, so that it serves as a reference to the community

Comment: @clint  - Done :)  Sorry it took so long.

Comment: hey nps, thanks and you have a good day !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code Correction**

As per OP, below correction fixed it

```
[NotMapped]
public string fullname
{
    get { return v_lastname + ", " + v_firstname + ", " + h_phone; }
}
```